# Which NBA player has the most career shots?

Tags: basketball, statistics, nba

Which NBA basketball player has attempted the most shots in their career, and how many of them did they make?

Answer (score 3):

That would be Kareem Abdul-Jabbar. He attempted 28,307 shots and made 15,837 of them.

Per [Basketball](https://www.basketball-reference.com/leaders/fga_career.html) Reference